# Magento 2: "Store credit" Rest API not working

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3.0, store-credit

I am use `Store Credit` Rest API. But it is gives error `Request does not match any route`

> Method: POST
>
> Request URL:
>   http://localhost/magento/rest/V1/carts/mine/balance/apply

I am passing params `cartId` and `creditAmount`

Below is the response of the API.

`Response:`

```
{
    "message": "Request does not match any route.",
    "trace": null
}
```

Any have idea how to make work `Store Credit` Rest API.

Any help would be appropriated. Thanks.